# Django All_auth/rest_auth e-mail address validation using HTTP GET request

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I use *Django* *all_auth* and *rest_auth* for a backend service of a *mobile* app.
I integrated the registration and login API and all works fine.

Now I have to integrate the e-mail address validation logic.

After the registration (without social), I have to send an e-mail with the link that the user will use to validate your account.

I added this configurations into my *Django* settings:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

Also this works fine. I'm able to receive the e-mail after the registration of a new account. In the received e-mail I have the link to validate the account also.

I would like to have the validation of the e-mail when the user simply will click on the link.

So, I would like to use only the **GET HTTP** method.

I added, as suggested into the documentation, this setting also:

```
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
```

I use this url linked to the all_auth views.

```
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView
url(r'^account-confirm-email/', ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_email_verification_sent'),
url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

But, if I try to click on the link from the received mail, I obtain this error:

```
KeyError at /account-confirm-email/NzU:1hjl8A:z5Riy8Bjv_h0zJQtoYKuTkKvRLk/
'key'

/allauth/account/views.py in get
            self.object = self.get_object() ...
▶ Local vars
/allauth/account/views.py in get_object
        key = self.kwargs['key'] ...
▶ Local vars
```

This seams that setting is not sufficient to have the possibility to use the e-mail validation with GET method.

Have I to overwrite the custom Django view for this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the same view two times where you should use another view class. Following change should fix it:

```py
from allauth.account.views import ConfirmEmailView, EmailVerificationSentView

# ...

url(
    r'^account-confirm-email/',
    EmailVerificationSentView.as_view(),  # This is changed
    name='account_email_verification_sent',
),
url(
    r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$',
    ConfirmEmailView.as_view(),
    name='account_confirm_email',
),

# ...
```